# How to call shared_task asynchronously

Tags: python, django, celery

I have such celery-task

```
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def send_to_sap(user_id):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    if settings.SYNCHRONIZATION:
        response = requests.post(
            settings.SOME_URL,
            json={}
        )
```

And I want to execute it in asynchronous mode from view, and I'm trying to do this like this

```
from tasks import send_to_sap

def send_to_sap(request, pk):
    # some logic...
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        send_to_sap.apply_async(kwargs={'user_id': pk})
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
send_to_sap.delay(pk)
```

I should call using `delay()`